# Mysql: Need help by selecting every nth row

Tags: mysql, select, rows

Im searching for a way for selecting every row whichs id ends with f.e. "4". The search result should contain only following rows "4,14,24,34,44,54,64 etc..."

Is this possible in MYSQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select * from thetable where id like "%4";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tablename where id regexp '4$'
```